# Exclude a FULLTEXT field in a sphinx search

Tags: sphinx

This is partially to fully understand how sphinx works and partially to understand how to exclude a particular field.

If I have a sphinx query of

```
 SELECT ID, Title, Description, Type, Category, Price, Date, Sales FROM table;
```

Whereas Title, Description and Type are considered fulltext searches and ID, Category, Price, and Date are used for sorting.

I am assuming that Sphinx KNOWS to run it's keyword search based on the fact that Title, Description, etc. are all designated as FULLTEXT and therefore ignores Price, etc. since they are not FULLTEXT?

So, that said...  What if I want to exclude all of the FULLTEXT items and only search on one of them like Title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your other question, of which fields are searchable....

The first column in the `sql_query`, is ALWAYS taken as the document-id, after than **all** columns are automatically assumed to be `field`s. Unless you **specifically** request them to be made `attribute`s, with `sql_attr_*` definitions.

Sphinx completely ignores the ***type*** of the original database column. All values are transfered as strings anyway.

---

As a reminder...

- `field`s are full-text searchable. And can control which specific ones a specific query uses, using the field limit operator already mentioned.
- whereas `attribute`s are stored as is in the index, and not full-text searchable. However they can be used in filters, or for sorting and grouping. Attributes can also be included in the resultset.

(note however you can make a column both a `field` and `string attribute`, to get best of both, via `sql_field_string`)

Comment: Oh wow.... Ok, so you are saying unless I "tell" it that items are supposed to be attributes, Sphinx is going to think it's a field and search on it?  That's crucial info, if so.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

By default `MATCH('whatever text')` matches any of the text fields in your index. You can limit it to only specific fields by include a field search operator `@` such as `MATCH('@title whatever text')`. To ignore all fields, leave out `MATCH()` from the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You've got the syntax slighty wrong. The @title, must be BEFORE the words being searched, as the limit applies to all keywords that come ***after*** it, so `MATCH('@title whatever text')`